# Homology of two 2-genus with identified their boundaries

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider the topological space $X$, obtained by gluing two *solid* genus-2 surfaces at their boundary surfaces via the identity map.

Here is my solution which I am not sure. I have considered the pairs $(A\cup B, C\cup C)$ such that $C$ is the boundary of both them. So I can use the relative Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence associated to these pairs.
$$
\cdot\cdot\cdot\rightarrow H_n(A\cap B,C) \rightarrow H_n(A,C) \oplus H_n(B,C) \rightarrow H_n(A\cup B,C) \rightarrow \cdot \cdot \cdot
$$
As a result, since $A\cap B=C$, we have isomorphisms:
$\tilde{H}_n(A/C)\oplus\tilde{H}_n(B/C)=\tilde{H}_n(A\cup B/C)$. We have $A/C=B/C=S^2$ and $X=A\cup B/C$.